# js resizing images upon reload of page

Tags: javascript, html, image, resize

Just to start, I'm quite a novice to programming, but always wanted to get into it. As a first exercise I wanted to make a little gallery with html. So far so good. Then I came up with a little question that I tried to solve for myself: Is it possible to have the images resized within a range (let's say height varying from 1-1000px) upon everytime i reload the page. I tried several javascripts with a `var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);` command, but somehow don't manage. As much as I know there's no way to do it in CSS? So that height would be variable and change everytime, while width always adjusts....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <script>
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img.resizable');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
  imgs[i].style.setProperty('--image-height', Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1 + 'px');
</script>

<style>
  figure { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
    }

img.resizable {
  height : calc(var(--image-height));
  width: auto;
}

    figcaption{
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 2px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<main>

<figure>
  <img src="pic1" class = "resizable">
<figcaption>
    <p>CAPTIONimg1</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>


<figure>
  <img src="pic2" class = "resizable">
<figcaption>
    <p>CAPTIONimg2</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>


<figure>
  <img src="pic3" class = "resizable">
<figcaption>
    <p>CAPTIONimg3</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>


<figure>
  <img src="pic4" class = "resizable">
<figcaption>
    <p>CAPTIONimg4</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>


  <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there:

```
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');//SELECT ALL THE IMAGES
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {//ITERATE THROUGH ALL THE IMAGES
       images[i].style.height=Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);//APPLY THE RANDOM HEIGHT TO EACH IMAGE
       images[i].style.width="auto";//MAKE THE WIDTH CORRESPOND PROPORTIONALLY
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways but here is one using css variables:

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img.resizable');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
  imgs[i].style.setProperty('--image-height', Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1 + 'px');
}
```

```css
img.resizable {
  height : calc(var(--image-height));
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class = "resizable" src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
<img class = "resizable" src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
```

Comment: looks like a great solution! the js though would need to go in front of every image, is that correct? or can I just have it at the beginning wouldn't it then calculate the same height for every image? thanks!

Comment: @flo well depends if you want the same scaling for all images or one for each

Comment: actually I thought for having every image scaled on it's own, then I guess the CSS tag is not sufficient, am I correct? is it possible to just define every height value with a script?

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just edited the code above, somehow I'm missing out on the whole thing, nothing seems to work :I I'm sorry, quite new to this...

Comment: @flo you are missing the closing } from the for loop. Also, you need to enclose the code with window.onload = function(){...}. If not, code will run before image nodes are rendered so there will be 0 elements to change height at that time

Comment: probably a small step for you, but a giant one for me! Thank you a lot!